# Positioning text at bottom of a background image

Tags: html, css

I need to position a text element at the bottom of a background-image.

```
<div style="background-image: url('http://www.hdwallpapersinn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/1325120512b60-45927-1.jpg'); height:100px">
    <p class="caption">Test</p>
</div>


.caption{
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/K98CR/

This will position the element at the bottom of the page and not at the bottom of the background image. My understanding of the "bottom" property is that it can be relative to its parent element, but it is not working in this case.

Anything I am missing? Or any other way to accomplish this? Using a margin-top is not an option as I am creating a fluid layout and that would depend on screen ratio and I do not want that.

What I want is a way to position an element at the bottom of its parent element. In this case, I want to position text at the bottom of an image styled with "background-image".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `postion: relative;` to your background image `div` will fix it.

```
<div style="background-image: url('http://www.hdwallpapersinn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/1325120512b60-45927-1.jpg'); height:100px; position: relative;">
    <p class="caption">Test</p>
</div>
```

[LIVE EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rahilwazir/4aptn9Ld/)

**w3schools**:

> An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first
>   parent element that has a position other than static. If no such
>   element is found, the containing block is <html>